# After Refreshing Context SBA-Client in SBA-UI -Environment, showing status as DOWN

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, spring-boot-admin

In Spring Boot Admin, initially registering the rest service(SBA-client) and can view all the info.
But when i am trying to refresh the context after updating yaml properites in Environment tab, service status is going down though service is UP.
able to see status as UP in **localhost:portnumber/actuator/health**

1. Above service is registering to eureka discovery
2. Service is authenticated using BASIC Authentication.
   In bootstarp properties/yaml giving below fields:
   spring.boot.admin.client.instance.metadata.user.name=username
   spring.boot.admin.client.instance.metadata.user.password=password

Below are the logs for eureka discovery:

```
c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Registered instance service-name/service-name:152307399 with status UP (replication=false)
c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Registered instance service-name/service-name:152307399 with status UP (replication=true)
c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Cancelled instance service-name/service-name:152307399 (replication=false)
c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Registered instance service-name/service-name:680805597 with status UP (replication=false)
c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : DS: Registry: cancel failed because Lease is not registered for: service-name/service-name:152307399
c.n.eureka.resources.InstanceResource    : Not Found (Cancel): service-name - service-name:152307399
INFO [-,b94f117edd71e6da,b94f117edd71e6da,false] 17648 --- [nio-8761-exec-1] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Registered instance service-name/service-name:680805597 with status UP (replication=true)
c.n.eureka.cluster.ReplicationTask       : The replication of task service-name/service-name:152307399:Cancel@localhost failed with response code 404
c.netflix.eureka.cluster.PeerEurekaNode  : service-name/service-name:152307399:Cancel@localhost: missing entry.
```

Below are the Spring boot admin logs

```
 INFO 16348 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] d.c.b.admin.server.services.InfoUpdater  : Couldn't retrieve info for Instance(id=1iu7yh611233, version=3, registration=Registration(name=service-name, managementUrl=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator, healthUrl=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator/health, serviceUrl=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/, source=http-api), registered=true, statusInfo=StatusInfo(status=UP, details={hystrix={status=UP}, diskSpace={status=UP, details={total=298596691968, free=248679415808, threshold=10485760}}, configServer={status=UP, details={propertySources=[file:/D:/service-name.yml]}}, refreshScope={status=UP}, discoveryComposite={status=UP, details={discoveryClient={status=UP, details={services=[]}}, eureka={description=Remote status from Eureka server, status=UNKNOWN, details={applications={}}}}}, db={status=UP, details={defaultDs={status=UP, details={database=Oracle, hello=1}}}}}), statusTimestamp=2020-09-05T14:52:37.316Z, info=Info(values={}), endpoints=Endpoints(endpoints={httptrace=Endpoint(id=httptrace, url=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator/httptrace), loggers=Endpoint(id=loggers, url=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator/loggers), refresh=Endpoint(id=refresh, url=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator/refresh), health=Endpoint(id=health, url=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator/health), env=Endpoint(id=env, url=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator/env), heapdump=Endpoint(id=heapdump, url=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator/heapdump), features=Endpoint(id=features, url=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator/features), mappings=Endpoint(id=mappings, url=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator/mappings), scheduledtasks=Endpoint(id=scheduledtasks, url=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator/scheduledtasks), archaius=Endpoint(id=archaius, url=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator/archaius), configprops=Endpoint(id=configprops, url=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator/configprops), beans=Endpoint(id=beans, url=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator/beans), threaddump=Endpoint(id=threaddump, url=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator/threaddump), metrics=Endpoint(id=metrics, url=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator/metrics), conditions=Endpoint(id=conditions, url=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator/conditions), auditevents=Endpoint(id=auditevents, url=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator/auditevents), service-registry=Endpoint(id=service-registry, url=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator/service-registry), jolokia=Endpoint(id=jolokia, url=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator/jolokia), info=Endpoint(id=info, url=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator/info)}), buildVersion=null, tags=Tags(values={})): 401
 INFO 16348 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] d.c.b.admin.server.services.InfoUpdater  : Couldn't retrieve info for Instance(id=1iu7yh611233, version=4, registration=Registration(name=service-name, managementUrl=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator, healthUrl=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator/health, serviceUrl=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/, source=http-api), registered=true, statusInfo=StatusInfo(status=DOWN, details={error=Unauthorized, status=401}), statusTimestamp=2020-09-05T14:53:05.140Z, info=Info(values={}), endpoints=Endpoints(endpoints={httptrace=Endpoint(id=httptrace, url=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator/httptrace), loggers=Endpoint(id=loggers, url=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator/loggers), health=Endpoint(id=health, url=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator/health), refresh=Endpoint(id=refresh, url=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator/refresh), env=Endpoint(id=env, url=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator/env), heapdump=Endpoint(id=heapdump, url=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator/heapdump), features=Endpoint(id=features, url=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator/features), scheduledtasks=Endpoint(id=scheduledtasks, url=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator/scheduledtasks), mappings=Endpoint(id=mappings, url=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator/mappings), archaius=Endpoint(id=archaius, url=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator/archaius), beans=Endpoint(id=beans, url=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator/beans), configprops=Endpoint(id=configprops, url=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator/configprops), threaddump=Endpoint(id=threaddump, url=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator/threaddump), metrics=Endpoint(id=metrics, url=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator/metrics), conditions=Endpoint(id=conditions, url=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator/conditions), auditevents=Endpoint(id=auditevents, url=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator/auditevents), service-registry=Endpoint(id=service-registry, url=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator/service-registry), info=Endpoint(id=info, url=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator/info), jolokia=Endpoint(id=jolokia, url=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator/jolokia)}), buildVersion=null, tags=Tags(values={})): 401
 INFO 16348 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] d.c.b.admin.server.services.InfoUpdater  : Couldn't retrieve info for Instance(id=1iu7yh611233, version=5, registration=Registration(name=service-name, managementUrl=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator, healthUrl=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator/health, serviceUrl=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/, source=http-api), registered=true, statusInfo=StatusInfo(status=DOWN, details={error=Unauthorized, status=401}), statusTimestamp=2020-09-05T14:53:05.140Z, info=Info(values={}), endpoints=Endpoints(endpoints={httptrace=Endpoint(id=httptrace, url=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator/httptrace), loggers=Endpoint(id=loggers, url=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator/loggers), refresh=Endpoint(id=refresh, url=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator/refresh), health=Endpoint(id=health, url=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator/health), env=Endpoint(id=env, url=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator/env), heapdump=Endpoint(id=heapdump, url=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator/heapdump), mappings=Endpoint(id=mappings, url=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator/mappings), scheduledtasks=Endpoint(id=scheduledtasks, url=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator/scheduledtasks), configprops=Endpoint(id=configprops, url=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator/configprops), threaddump=Endpoint(id=threaddump, url=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator/threaddump), metrics=Endpoint(id=metrics, url=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator/metrics), auditevents=Endpoint(id=auditevents, url=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator/auditevents), jolokia=Endpoint(id=jolokia, url=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator/jolokia), info=Endpoint(id=info, url=http://abc2zcompany.com:12345/actuator/info)}), buildVersion=null, tags=Tags(values={})): 401
```

Could any one please help me with this issue, thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you use a randomized password for accessing the actuator endpoints? Does the password change when refreshing the context but is not updated in SBA?

Comment: No, just single password(encrypted) which retrieves from yaml file. Sba-client(rest microservice) is using Basic authentication. Problem is with authenticated services. When I enabled SBA for eureka discovery (No authentication) service its registering properly even after refreshcontext. Thank you.